# Why external website that i embed in my website iframe will auto redirect to the external website pages

Tags: html, iframe

As above, I use normal iframe to embed external website to my own website, but when I go to that page with the external website embed on it, it will automatically redirect to the external website.

I dont want the redirect to happen, is there any solution?

Comment: Can you show us an example? The external website will likely have some Javascript code that it is executing on it's parent window if it exists. You may be able to stop it from executing.

Comment: http://infiledge.site88.net/materialcontent.php?mid=107
The above link can show an example of the problem I am facing. Is there a way to stop the javascript from executing?

Comment: ShreejiShah was correct, there is `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">if(top.frames.length > 0)
top.location.href=self.location;
</script>` on the page which is telling the parent to redirect to itself, basically meaning it can be included as an iframe. I will post an answer as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Ian Jamieson really hope to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of code similar to this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(top.location != window.location) {
     window.location = top.location;
   }
</script>
```

And sad to say that.. There is no Solution for that! :(

Comment: tried this code but it didnt solve the issue.... I am quite noob in javascript so sorry

Comment: This is the code that the external website has. So you can't edit this.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that this code is on website you are trying to display in iFrame.. you can't edit their code of course.. If you put it in your site.. then you site will prevent another websites from being displayed in their iFrames.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could ajax load the page, however this would not be possible due to cross domain policy. So instead the only other solution I can think of would be to use [PHP's cURL library](https://www.php.net/curl), something like this may help:

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://davidwalsh.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution that can use sandbox attribute on iframe:

The sandbox attribute enables an extra set of restrictions for the content in the iframe.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Then iframe will no longer be able to redirect parent.

in my case I used iframe with some values to allow script and allow same origin for embedded site

```
<iframe id="" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="http://www.example.com/" ></iframe>
```